# Ansible: Simple comparison failing when comparing integers

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I have the following:

```yaml
- set_fact:
   test_string: "{{ htmlres.content | regex_search('test-([0-9]+)', '\\1') | first}}"
```

This retrieves `2` which is part of a string contained in the `htmlres.content` content which is `test-2`.

So now I'm trying to compare the result of that output and fail the execution if it is not 2, so I tried this:

```yaml
- name: Fail if test_string is not 2
  fail: msg="Incorrect string. Expected 2, but instead got {{ test_string }}"
  when: test_string != 2
```

However I've outputted the contents of test_string and I know for a fact that it is 2. Why is it failing?

I've tried adding `| string` and `| int` to the end of `test_string` since my first though is that it would be an issue with type comparison, but that didn't work either.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a debug output of `test_string`.

Comment: Also ``htmlres.content`` seems to be needed. https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Answer (score 4):

Unless [jinja2_native](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-jinja2-native) is enabled, the result of templating is always a string. You need to take that into account in your comparison.

```yaml
- name: Fail if test_string is not 2
  fail: msg="Incorrect string. Expected 2, but instead got {{ test_string }}"
  when: test_string | int != 2
```

or

```yaml
- name: Fail if test_string is not 2
  fail: msg="Incorrect string. Expected 2, but instead got {{ test_string }}"
  when: test_string != '2'
```